# Работа с вложенными статичными страницами

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Задача в следующем: Мне нужно выводить на сайте статичную страницу "О нас", и еще статичные страницы внутри нее (О нас → Миссия, О нас → Цели и задачи, и так далее).

По рекомендациям решил так:

**routes.rb**

```
resources :about,  path: '', only: :show
```

**AboutController**

```
class AboutController < ApplicationController
  add_breadcrumb "Главная", :root_path
  add_breadcrumb "О нас", :about_index_url

  def show
    if partial_name_correct?
      render partial_name
    else
      not_found
    end
  end

  private

  def partial_name
    params[:id].underscore
  end

  def partial_name_correct?
    %w(about
       about/mission
       about/otziv
       about/rukovodstvo
       about/sostav
       about/tseli).include? params[:id]
  end
end
```

Но появилась проблема - рельсы никак не хотят работать с внутренними страницами вида `about/mission`.

По рекомендациям использовал вот такое:

```
<li><%=link_to 'Миссия', about_path('about/id?=mission')%></li>
```

Но не работает. Что-то где-то пошло не так, как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как выяснилось, приводимый выше код с `partial_name_correct?` и другими приемами для вывода статичных страниц - не умеет работать с вложенностью в пути. Во-первых, рельса экранирует слеш в `page_path('about/mission')` (и в `url` оказывается `/about%2Fmission`), во-вторых так элегантно отловить и отрендерить вьюху по имени в контроллере уже не выйдет.

Что я бы сделал в такой ситуации:

1. Завел бы неймспейс `about`;
2. В нем по `root`-роуту - выводил бы вьюху отдельного контроллера;
3. А внутренние статичные страницы ловил бы тем же методом в `PagesController`.

Код стал бы таким:

```
# routes.rb
namespace :about do
  resources :pages, path: '', only: : show
  root to: welcome#index
end

# app/controllers/about/welcome_controller.rb
class About::WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index; end
end

# app/controllers/about/welcome_controller.rb
class About::PagesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    if partial_name_correct?
      render partial_name
    else
      not_found
    end
  end

  private

  def partial_name
    params[:id].underscore
  end

  def partial_name_correct?
    %w(mission
       otziv
       rukovodstvo
       sostav
       tseli).include? params[:id]
  end
end
```

А вьюхи бы лежали по этим путям:

```
app/views/about/welcome/index.html
app/views/about/pages/mission.html
app/views/about/pages/otziv.html
app/views/about/pages/rukovodstvo.html
app/views/about/pages/sostav.html
app/views/about/pages/tseli.html
```